# Multiple DAS in Glassfish 3.1

Tags: glassfish-3

Is it possible to create more than one DAS in Glassfish? In fact I want to build a redundacy arhitecture in case server is down physically. In other words if machine hosting DAS is down, administration operation will not be affected and other instance will take the admin control.

Besides I know that instances managed by DAS is not affected and all of them keep running without requiring any DAS.

The reason why I need such architecture is that I have a monitoring program that connect the DAS and get statistics and other information about instances. If DAS is down I do not know how to get this information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the thread of a java forum. It is not possible to create more than one DAS. 
Here's [a link](http://forums.java.net/node/790171)!